# wso2esb how to use the pattern param from property mediator

Tags: wso2, hateoas, wso2-esb

I would like to parse the Location header send back by the back end server to rewrite it before sending it to the client. I tried this but doesn't work, I mean that the Location header is empty. I tried without the pattern param and it works well I can have the Location header well defined in response from the client side.

```
<property expression="get-property('LocationHeaderFromBackEnd')"
            name="Location" pattern="v1.*" scope="transport"/>
```

The property LocationHeaderFromBackEnd = "http://host:port/v1/resource/uid"

Could someone provide some help ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use JavaScript mediator to handle the regex like below. I hope you can provide me a better one :)

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var str = mc.getProperty("LocationHeaderFromBackEnd");
        var re = /.v1.*/; 

    var m;

    if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        // eg m[0] etc.
    }
    mc.setProperty("LocationHeaderParsed",  m[0]);]]>
   </script>
   <property expression="get-property('LocationHeaderParsed')" name="Location" scope="transport"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pattern in property.

For example my property value is

DecodeUrl = **"message_id=dd0f-678a-5678&response=ok"**

for get message_id and response we can use this code:

```
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           name="message_id"
           expression="get-property('DecodeUrl')"
           pattern="(message\_id\=)(.*)(&amp;)(.*)"
           group="2"/>
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           name="response"
           expression="get-property('DecodeUrl')"
           pattern="(message\_id\=)(.*)(&amp;)(response=)(.*)"
           group="5"/>
 <log level="custom">
```

output:

dd0f-678a-5678

ok

**The index number in group is important.**